# Win32-DLL to UWP-DLL

Tags: dll, uwp, visual-studio-2017, win-universal-app

I'm using Visual Studio 2017 on Windows 10. I try to convert a Win32-DLL to a UWP-DLL. However, when I compile I got this Error:

```
1>Build FAILED.
1>
1>error PRI175 : 0x80004005 - Processing Resources failed with error : Unbekannter Fehler
1>GENERATEPROJECTPRIFILE : error PRI261: 0xdef00523 - Named resource 'Files\CRenderer\..\..\..\Products\CRenderer\CRenderer\CompiledShaders\GS_GenerateNormals.cso' is outside project root! Only resource containers are allowed outside the project root.
1>    1 Warning(s)
1>    2 Error(s)
1>
1>Time Elapsed 00:00:00.78
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

The *.hlsl shaders compile correctly and are stored in the folder "CompiledShaders". In the file "layout.resfiles" the path is specified as "CRenderer......\Products\CRenderer\CRenderer\CompiledShaders\GS_GenerateNormals.cso" (instead of simply "CompiledShaders\GS_GenerateNormals.cso").
When I set the “layout.resfiles” file to read-only, VS writes: Task 'GeneratePriConfigurationFiles' failed.

To convert Win32-dll to UWP-dll, I recompiled the linked libs and then the dll-project with these project properties:
Configuration Properties> General> Windows Store App Support> Yes
Configuration Properties> c / c ++> Code Generation> Runtime Library> MD / MDd
unloaded, inserted these tags and reloaded:

```
<Default Language> en-US </ Default Language>
<Minimum Visual Studio Version> 14.0 </ minimum Visual Studio version>
<AppContainerApplication> true </ AppContainerApplication>
<ApplicationType> Windows Store </ ApplicationType>
<Windows Target Platform Version> 10.0.15063.0 </ Windows Target Platform Version>
<WindowsTargetPlatformMinVersion> 10.0.14393.0 </ WindowsTargetPlatformMinVersion>
<Application Type Revision> 10.0 </ Application Type Revision>
```

Then rebuild. Afterwards, I solved the unresolved errors. The functions, that are not supported by UWP were changed and the parts of the code that are not working and needed are excluded by preprocessor definition.

```
Configuration Properties> c / c ++> Preprocessor -> Preprocessor Definitions> "WIN_UWP"
(In the code:) #ifndef WIN_UWP [Function(){…}] #endif)
```

Comment: Could you share more detail about how to convert Win32-Dll to UWP-Dll?

Comment: Hi Nico thanks for your interest. I edited the Question, hope that helps.

Comment: Do you mean that you have solved your issue?

Comment: No, still the error “outside of the Project root”. I just tried to explain more exact my approach to convert the win32-dll to an UWP-dll.

Comment: Have you tried to check this article for porting win32 dll to UWP: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/porting/how-to-use-existing-cpp-code-in-a-universal-windows-platform-app?

Comment: Yes, I read this articel. My problem occurs between 6. and 7. under "Using a Win32 DLL in a Universal Windows Platform App". I was able to solve the errors described there, but not the ones I get now.